# How to choose the correct email address in gmail app?

Tags: contacts, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-4, gmail

If I have two different email address from the same contact like:

- firstname.lastname@private.com
- firstname.lastname@job.com

When I need to send a new e-mail I am not able to choose the right one because it displays only the first part of the email address.

So I can only view "firstname" and the first part of the lastname...
It happened very often with my contacts with the original Gmail app.

How can I solve it?

[image: screenshot of the app]

Comment: Does turning the phone in landscape mode show longer address?

Comment: Yes it does, but it is longer (only few instants, but if I could solve it I will be happy)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can type a few letters of domain name that you want after a space to get other addresses filtered out. In general, you can type several parts of a email address separating them by spaces to find only contacts that contain all specified parts.

For example, if you have the following email addresses in your contacts:

```
john.doe@home.com
john.doe@work.com
john.smith@home.com
john.smith@work.com
```

Than you can type something like `john.d w` or `j doe w` or even `j d w` to get only the first one in the auto completion popup.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your email you will have star, reply, forward and the 3 dots. Underneath that you will have from who, then the time, and to:. On the same line where is shows (to:) there is arrow pointing down, click on that and it will expand and show from and reply-to full address. Should have no problem seeing ending of addresses now.

Good luck!

Comment: I am not able to view the "arrow pointing down" (I use standard GMail app)

Comment: @Ale that is on Gmail

Comment: @Ale the arrow looks like this (>), only pointing downward. I have the Gmail app installed.

Comment: in the attacched image you can see I have no arrow in the field. It do not appear if I start to write a name

Comment: I think HasH_BrowN is referring to a received email whereas Ale is asking about how to see the full email address when creating a new email.

Comment: @bmdixon went back and saw the picture again,  and your right.  There still should be some drop down when Ale types so as to see contacts with that name, when in landscape the whole email address should show

Comment: as soon as you type into the TO text field any saved contact with the letters/symbols/numbers typed will show up in a drop down menu. If they aren't saved they will not show. Also if the theme/color of background/color of font is matching the drop down you will not see whats there. But as to not seeing the endings of the email address, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Ale  spent a couple of hours researching on this, the best i could find for this question is this: *https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/gmail/tNbT7V0zLXs*. Basically what this says is that your email information for your contacts are in the wrong fields. See if this will solve your problem, if it does I will edit my answer to reflect it.